# How to run a java application (eclipse) on command prompt?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

I'm new to eclipse, please help!

I have coded a java project on Eclipse which contains many classes. How can I run the application on Windows command prompt. Please give detailed, step by step guidance. I tried searching on this site, but none of them worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the project as a jar file from the eclipse.
follow [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse) link to know about exporting project [LINK](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)
 Run this jar file from the command prompt

```
java -jar xxx.jar
```